# Docusign integration with Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, integration, docusignapi

Recently I was Creating sandbox docusign developer account and also it is integrating with Dynamics 365 I am trying to send a Document to the customer with " send with ducusign" it is loading not opened.

I am trying to sign a document with "sign with Docusign" it is opened but I am getting this kind of error:

```
We could not find any documents eligible to DocuSign in the notes section for Signing.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using this feature you need to make sure you have an attachment in the notes of the entity (Opportunity, Account etc.) that you're using in Dynamics and you can sign or send the document(s) that is attached there.